# Docker Desktop Failing to start

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-machine, hyper-v, docker-desktop

i have installed Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b on my windows 10 machine. But i am not able to run docker succesfully , its giving an exception as below all the time .I have uninstalled docker , restarted the machine and installed again,the issue still persists.Hyper V is enabled at bios level , and the process is running as well.I have disabled and enabled the hyper v feature , still the issue persisits.

Exception trace.

Docker.Core.DockerException:
Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException:
Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 688
at , : line 811
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
   at Docker.Backend.BackendNamedPipeServer.b__8_2(Object[] args)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:
  Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D).
  at Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 688
  at , : line 811
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)

```
 Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException:
 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
```

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

```
 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D)
```

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 6AA21F0C-7B13-48E0-B29D-68E8E2D4398D).

```
     Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualizationOperationFailedException:
     'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
```

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.
            at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.View.EndMethodReturnInternal(IVMTask task, VirtualizationOperation operation, Boolean affectedElementExpected)
            at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VMComputerSystemBaseView.EndSetState(IVMTask setStateTask)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ConvertActionToFunction>b__0(T x)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.PerformOperationWithReturn[T](IOperationWatcher watcher, Func`1 startTaskMethod, Func`2 endTaskMethod, String taskDescription, VirtualizationObject targetObject)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine.ChangeState(VirtualMachineAction action, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM.ProcessOneOperand(VirtualMachine vm, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdlet`1.ProcessOperands(IList`1 operands, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)

at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean withNotifications)
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()